# jgit - clone a branch of a repo without a checkout

Tags: repository, branch, clone, jgit

The CloneRepository command seems to ignore the setBranch parameter if you aren't doing a checkout.  Is there a way to specify the branch ( instead of the master )?  I don't want to checkout the entire branch but I want to add a file to that branch ( add, commit, and push )

Answer (score 2):

This works for me when I use the [existing snippet for cloning](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java) from the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) and only add the following at line 33:

```
            .setBranch("email")
```

After the snippet is executed, the local clone in the temporary directory has the given branch checked out.

Another option might be to use `org.eclipse.jgit.storage.dfs.InMemoryRepository` to clone a Git repo in-memory and work from there.

Comment: Did you have .setNoCheckout(true)?  When it is set to false, you are correct.  But when set to true, the local directory is not tracked to the branch specified - instead it tracks to master.  git status confirms the current tracking.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if that is possible, as soon as you want to add something to the branch, you need to have a checkout as far as I know. Or are you able to do this with commandline git?

Comment: I was looking at the test https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L107-L154 .  It uses RefUpdate objects to "fool" git into thinking a commit has been checked out.  I'm not clear on how this test works but was hoping the key to making git think the working repository was in a particular state.  I haven't been able to get the command line to do what I want - I always have to do a CO.

Comment: i was looking to clone a particular branch other than master. Helped. Thanks!